# C++: Storing resources whose copy operation is unreasonable or impossible

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, move-constructor

I want to write a `ContentManager` class which loads and maintains different types of assets for a game (compare with [XNA's ContentManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.aspx)).
My header file looks like the following:

```
class ContentManager
{
public:
  ContentManager(Direct3D& d3d, const std::string& rootDirectory = "Resource");
 ~ContentManager();

  template<typename T>
  const T& Load(const std::string& assetName);

private:
  Direct3D& d3d_;
  std::string rootDirectory_;

  std::map<std::string, Texture> textures_;
};
```

As you can see, I have a map for each asset type (only for textures at the moment) and a generic `Load<T>()` method, which I instantiate explicitly for each asset type I want to store. `Load<Texture>()` reads an image file from disk (if it's not already in the map), creates a new `Texture`, inserts it into the map and returns it.

My `Texture` class basically creates and encapsulates a raw `IDirect3DTexture9` to follow the `RAII` idiom (the destructor calls `Release()` on the `texture_`):

```
class Texture
{
public:
  Texture();
  Texture(Direct3D& d3d, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& stream);

  ~Texture();

  IDirect3DTexture9* GetD3DTexture() const { return texture_; }

private:
  IDirect3DTexture9* texture_;
};
```

When testing my code, I realized that each texture was released twice, because (shallow) copies of the `Texture` objects were created at some point, and the destructor was called for each of these, of course.

Furthermore, although `Load<T>()` returns a reference to an element of the map, the caller could make a copy himself and trigger the same problem. My thoughts:

- Making the copy constructor of `Texture` private is no solution, since copies are required anyway when creating an `std::pair` to insert a new element into the map.
- Defining a custom copy constructor, which creates a deep copy, doesn't seem to be reasonable at all, since I would need to create a copy of the underlying Direct3D texture, which should really exist only once.

So what are my options here? Could this be solved by using smart pointers? Which type should be stored in the map and which type should `Load<T>()` return?

Comment: Look up rvalues and move assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++11, the language added a feature called moving for *exactly* the reason you are encountering.  And luckily, modifying your code to use move mechanics is amazingly simple:

```
class Texture
{
public:
  Texture() noexcept;
  Texture(Direct3D& d3d, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& stream);

  Texture(Texture&& rhs) noexcept
  : texture_(rhs.texture_) //take the content from rhs
  {rhs.texture_ = nullptr;} //rhs no longer owns the content

  Texture& operator=(Texture&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    Clear(); //erase previous content if any
    texture_ = rhs.texture_; //take the content from rhs
    rhs.texture_ = nullptr; //rhs no longer owns the content
    return *this;
  }

  ~Texture() noexcept {Clear();}

  IDirect3DTexture9* GetD3DTexture() const noexcept { return texture_; }

private:
  void Clear() noexcept; //does nothing if texture_ is nullptr
  IDirect3DTexture9* texture_;
};
```

This adds a "move constructor" and a "move assignment", which will  *move* the content from one `Texture` to another, so that only one points to a given `IDirect3DTexture9` at a time.  The compiler should detect these two, and stop generating the implicit copy constructor and copy assignment, so your `Texture` can no longer be copied, which is exactly what you wanted, since deep-copying a `IDirect3DTexture9` is hard and doesn't even really make sense.  The Texture class is now magically fixed.

Now, what about the other classes?  No changes. `std::map<std::string, Texture>` is smart enough to detect that your class has `noexcept` move operators, and so it will use them automatically instead of copies.  It also makes the `map` itself movable but not copiable.  And since the `map` is movable but not copiable, that automagically makes `ContentManager` movable but not copiable.  Which makes sense when you think about it, moving content around is fine, but you don't want to *copy* all of that.  So those don't need any changes

---

Now, since rvalues is obviously a new concept to you, here's a crash course:

```
Texture getter(); //returns a temporary Texture
Texture a = getter(); //since the right hand side is a temporary,
                        //the compiler will try to move construct it, and only 
                        //copy construct if it can't be moved.
a = getter(); //since the right hand side is a temporary,
                        //the compiler will try to move assign it, and only 
                        //copy assign if it can't be moved.

void setter1(Texture&); //receives a reference to an outside texture object
setter1(a); //works exactly as it always has
setter1(getter()); //compiler error, reference to temporary
setter1(std::move(a)); //compiler error, passing rreference && instead of lreference &.

void setter2(Texture); //receives a local texture object
setter2(a); //compiler error, no copy constructor
setter1(getter()); //creates the Texture by moving the data from the temporary
setter2(std::move(a)); //The compiler moves the content from a to the function;
                      //the function receives the content previously held by a, and 
                      //a now has no content.  Careful not to read from a after this.

void setter3(Texture&&); //receives a reference to a temporary texture
setter3(a); //compiler error, a is not a temporary
setter3(getter()); //function receives reference to the temporary, all is good
setter3(std::move(a)); //function thinks a is temporary, and will probably remove 
                       //it's content. Careful not to read from a after this.
```

Comment: Thanks, C++11 is indeed new to me and I have to read about the new features, soon. ;) I have one more question: Is it still correct to let `Load<T>()` return a reference to a Texture of the map like `return textures_[assetName];`? Wouldn't this allow to move a Texture into a local variable and thus "steal" it from the content manager, since moving clears everything in the original object?

Comment: @ph4nt0m: locals and l-references (`T&`) will never have their content moved unless tell it explicitly with `std::move` (or if you return a local variable, it's moved from implicitly).  Since the function returns `const T&`, nobody can remove the content via that reference, so your map is safe.  C++11 replaced some copies with moves by default, but if it didn't copy before, it won't copy or move now, so old code is still just as safe.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand all of this correctly yet, since it's all new for me. But I thought of something like `Texture t = content.Load<Texture>("tex.png");`. Is this a move or a copy construct? I think it uses the usual copy constructor, so when `t` goes out of scope, the internal D3D texture is released which is not what I want since the `ContentManager` should be responsible for releasing the resources it manages.

Comment: @ph4nt0m: `content.Load` returns a constant reference to the `Texture` in the map.  Since it's not movable, `Texture t = ` would normally try to copy it, but since `Textures` are not copiable, it will give a compiler error instead.  You probably want `const Texture& t =...` since you probably want `t` to refer to the existing `Texture`, not make a new local `Texture` object.

Comment: I'm slowly beginning to understand.;) But why is `Texture` not copiable? Is this due to the `noexcept` keyword? VS2010 doesn't seem to support it so I ommited it and my Texture apparently WAS copied (I thought `noexcept` would just state that this method will not throw and had nothing to do with the issue). I hope declaring an empty private copy constructor and copy assignment operator will do as a workaround untill I switch to a modern compiler? :)

Comment: @ph4nt0m: If you manually type a move constructor/assignment in a class, the compiler shouldn't create copy constructor/assignment operators automatically anymore.  For Visual Studio 2010, you can use `throw()` instead of `noexcept`, since they don't have that feature yet.  It might work.  Without `noexcept`, containers (including map) will use copies instead of moves to keep from accidentally corrupting data if an exception is thrown.  Declaring a empty private copy constructor and assignment may help as well for MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor private.
Make a map that holds a pointer to the object instead of the object itself.

Comment: No need to introduce another layer of indirection, the language has built in mechanics to address exactly this issue

Answer (score 0):

The best is to keep a reference counter for each object. So instead, I would use a shared pointer (std::map< std::string, std::tr1::shared_ptr< ... > >).

You could also try to use the content manager to release the object as well (ie: Release( T &object )) and keep a reference counter in the map itself. But the best is the shared pointer..

Comment: No need to introduce another layer of indirection, the language has built in mechanics to address exactly this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would suggest using smart pointers for this. In particular you could use `shared_ptr` Depending on your compiler version or the frameworks available, you might want want to use the [C++11 variety](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or e.g. [Boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Comment: No need to introduce another layer of indirection, the language has built in mechanics to address _exactly_ this issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right at your finger tips: do not use `insert` :)

1. You forgot the rule of Big Three: if you write any of copy constructor, copy assignment operator or destructor, you should most probably write the other two. In this case, make them private
2. There are many ways to insert elements in a `map`, `insert` is just one of them

Pure C++03 solution:

```
class Texture
{
public:
  Texture(): texture_(0) {}

  Load(Direct3D& d3d, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, 
       const std::vector<unsigned char>& stream);

  ~Texture();

  IDirect3DTexture9* GetD3DTexture() const { return texture_; }

private:
  IDirect3DTexture9* texture_;
};


template<typename T>
T const& ContentManager::Load(const std::string& assetName) {
    Texture& t = textures_[assetName];

    t.Load(....);

    return ...;
}
```

Now, you first place the object in the map (using its default constructor) and *then* actually fill it.

In C++11, you have two more alternatives:

- define a move constructor to be able to relocate the object
- use `emplace` and target the `piecewise_construct` constructor of pair as in `textures_.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(assetName), std::make_tuple(...));`